# How to change the border color of a button in libGdx?

Tags: java, libgdx, game-development

How to change the border color of a button? I know how to change the background, but I don’t know this, although I reviewed the entire documentation. And is it possible to find out whether the button is pressed or not

Answer (score 1):

To expand on MrStahlfelge's answer, if you are using buttons from the LibGDX scene2d package, then you can set different backgrounds for the button using ButtonStyle.

https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Button.ButtonStyle.html

Button has a constructor that takes a ButtonStyle so you can set all of this up when you create the button. There are also styles for ImageButton and TextButton if you are using one of these types of buttons.

With ButtonStyle you can set different Drawables for when the button is up, down, checked, mouse over, etc. and the button will automatically handle switching backgrounds for you depending on its state. You won't need to handle switching the backgrounds yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The background will become a border if you use a Ninepatch. I highly recommend to take a look at Skins and SkinComposer.

Add event listener to your button to get callbacks when it is pressed, or use the (surprise) `isPressed()` method.